# Excel transforma números en fechas

Tags: excel

Hola estoy haciendo una extracción de datos a un Excel a través de un dts y automáticamente se convierten algunos números en fechas. 
Por ejemplo, 2-12 a 2 Diciembre

Alguien sabe cómo evitar la conversión a fecha ?

Gracias.

Comment: Bueno, 2-12 no parece ser un numero... Quieres que eso se interprete como una formula (-10)  o como un string, o qué ?

Comment: " *estoy haciendo una extracción de datos* " <-- ¿cómo? ¿importando de un CSV, de otro orígen?

Comment: Como un string , leonbloy

Comment: Ya intente ponerle la comilla al principio barranka pero también la visualiza.

Comment: Puedes poner un espacio entre los guiones

Comment: ¿Exactamente qué sistema DTS estás usando?

Comment: Relacionado: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25506/forzar-n%C3%BAmeros-a-texto-en-excel

Answer (score 0):

Por regla general, Excel interpreta los valores que "parecen" fechas como fechas. Lo que puedes hacer es:

1. Poner una comilla antes del valor que estás escribiendo: `'2-12'`
2. Dar formato de Texto a la celda donde estás introduciendo el valor.

---

Si tu problema es más bien que pones un número en una celda con formato Fecha y te muestra efectivamente una fecha (por ejemplo, si escribes `1` y la celda toma el valor `01/01/1900`) esto se debe a que Excel (y en general todos los programas de MS Office) almacenan las fechas como números de tipo `Double`, donde la parte entera corresponde al número de días transcurridos desde el 1º de enero de 1900 y la parte decimal corresponde a la fracción de día (por ejemplo: `0.5` equivale a `12:00:00 PM`)

Answer (score 0):

El comportamiento normal de Excel, así como el de otras hojas de cálculo, es que los valores que coinciden con los formatos de fecha sean considerados como fecha, los cuales se guardan como número serializados.

Los usuarios que hacen uso intensivo de hojas de cálculo evitan los códigos que tienen formato similar a un formato de fecha, pero un problema es que los formatos de fecha varían con las configuración regional.

Si no te es posible cambiar la forma en la que se escriben los códigos, intenta colocar un apóstrofe como prefijo para indicar que el valor capturado debe ser tratado como texto. Si esto no funciona, agrega algo más, por ejemplo `C` y luego eliminalo en tu DTS.

**Referencias**

- [Mantener los ceros a la izquierda](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Mantener-los-ceros-a-1bf7b935-36e1-4985-842f-5dfa51f85fe7)